# Problemas con Ñ y SQLSERVER

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Tengo una Base de datos en SQLSERVER 2019 con colacion Modern_Spanish_CI_AS que me permite almacenar las letras ñ y caracteres especiales, pero cuando se visualiza la informacion en un formulario HTML este no me muestra las letras ñ.

En el header tengo como charset UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Estoy trabajando bajo IIS 10 (Windows 10) y PHP 7.4.

En el php.ini se adicionaron las siguientes lineas de código.

```
default_charset = UTF-8 
internal_encoding = UTF-8 
input_encoding = UTF-8 
output_encoding = TF-8 
mbstring.language = UTF-8 
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8 
mbstring.http_input = UTF-8
```

Imagenes.

[image: Información Formulario HTM]

[image: Información Base de Datos]

Este es el código que tengo en el modelo.

```
public function lista_paises()
{
    $respuesta = $this->con->db->execute('lista','paises','');
    foreach ($respuesta as $key)
    {
        echo utf8_decode("<option value='$key[0]'>$key[2]</option>");

    }
}
```

El cual se ejecuta a través de una clase que ejecuta los sql:

```
<?php
    class Sqlsrv{

        var $host;
        var $user;
        var $pass;
        var $dbName;

        function __construct($conf){
            $this->host = $conf['host'];
            $this->user = $conf['user'];
            $this->pass = $conf['pass'];
            $this->dbName = $conf['dbName'];
        }

        public function connect(){
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($this->host,array("UID"=>$this->user,"PWD"=>$this->pass,"Database"=>$this->dbName));
            return $conn;
        }

        public function execute($action,$table,$data){
            $cad = '';
            foreach ($data as $value) {
                $cad = $cad."'".$value."'".",";
            }
            $cad = substr($cad, 0, -1);
            $sql = "exec ps_".$action."_".$table." ".$cad;
            $conn = $this->connect();
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

            return $this->convertResult($result);
        }

        private function convertResult($result){
            $i = 0;
            while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
                $list[$i] = $rows;
                $i++;
            }
            return $list;
        }

        public function disconnect($conn){
            sqlsrv_close($conn);
        }
    }
?>
```

Necesito ayuda para que la letra ñ se visualice correctamente.

Quedo atento.

Comment: Por favor coloca el código `HTML` con el que construyes el `select`, creo que tu problema es con `PHP` y no con `SQL Server`. Saludos.

Comment: Intenta añadiendo el `CharSet` en el array de conexión  `sqlsrv_connect($this->host,array("UID"=>$this->user,"PWD"=>$this->pass,"Database"=>$this->dbName,"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"))`

Comment: Si eso no te funciona tambien veo que has colocado `echo utf8_decode("<option value='$key[0]'>$key[2]</option>");` y debería ser `echo utf8_encode("<option value='$key[0]'>$key[2]</option>");`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En la parte de respuestas, solo van las respuestas.